# Generate and send PDF file directly to a printer using Apache FOP.net or nFOP in C#/VB.Net

Tags: .net, pdf-generation, apache-fop, nfop

I am working on an application in .Net Frame in which I am using Apache FOP to generate and send pdf files directly to the printer.
 There are two parts of this application:
**1. Generate PDF files using .xml, .xsl and .fo files in .Net**
**2. Send the generated PDF file directly to the attached printer.**

I am successful in generating the PDF files using **[Apache FOP.Net/nFOP](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=65558) libraries**. But I am unable to send the generated file or formatted xml data (combined using .xml, .xsl,  .fo files) directly to the printer.

I have worked on Apache FOP in java and completed the application with both the features (File generation and printing). But now I have to develop these two features in .Net application.

It seems that there is no printing functionality available in the .net versions of Apache FOP. And I found some Printing Functions in Java applications using FOP but no help for .Net print using FOP. I did lot of research and checked many solutions available on the internet.

**NOTE:** I also worked with the java to .Net converted codes.  I used [**IKVM**](http://www.ikvm.net/) method but its not porting java code into my .net applications.

If you guys know how can I perform these task then please share your experiences here.

Suggestions and recommendations are welcome.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running a batch file from your .NET code
http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/output.html#general-direct-output

Comment: I didn't find any way to pass the parameters to this command. Can you show me how to pass parameters and call the command?